# Trim (remove frames from) live video from webcam using python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, video-capture

I have a webcam that captures video stream. After 30 seconds I want to remove 1 sec of the video from the start and keep capturing the video stream and so on. In short, I only want to save the latest 30 seconds of the live video.

OpenCV does not provide video processing

ffmpeg trims the video but creates a new output file, I don't want to keep copies.

```
#Create a video write before entering the loop
#Create a video write before entering the loop
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
    video_file, video_codec, fps, (int(cap.get(3)), int(cap.get(4)))
)

#video_file is the file being saved

start = time.time()
i=0
seconds='1'
while cap.isOpened():


    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
        if time.time() - start > 10:
            print('video > 10 sec')
        
            subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', video_file, '-ss', seconds, 'output.avi'])
            break

    # Write the frame to the current video writer
    video_writer.write(frame)
    if i%24 == 0:
        cv2.imwrite('image'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
    i+=1
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
else:
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I am looking for is how we can trip a live video and keep saving future frames so that the video don't exceed 30 seconds and keeps the latest frames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

```
ffmpeg -i input -f segment -segment_time 30 -segment_wrap 2 -reset_timestamps 1 output_%d.avi
```

This will create two files: `output_0.avi` and `output_1.avi`. Every 30 seconds the output will alternate between these files and overwrite earlier versions.

You could use `-segment_wrap 1` and only output 1 file, but you risk losing video. For example stopping recording at 32 seconds will leave you with a 2 second video instead of a 30 second video + a 2 second video.

Comment: can you make changes in the above program, I am not able to get the output using segment muxer

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I can only provide ffmpeg command. I don't use python. Question is about ffmpeg usage, not implementation into python. You can make a new question about how to get the command to work in python code.